# Using JQuery in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I tried to use **npm** to add jquery into a **Phoenix** project, but somehow **fsevents** just can't run under Win OS. So I just download jquery and put it under **/web/static/vendor** folder.

I try to understand what necessary to be done by reading [this](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets) article, but I just couldn't get it...

How can I access this jquery from my template page? A step by step tutorial would be great, because I really not familiar with node.js or brunch.

Thanks :)

Comment: Managing npm packages is, for me, the most channeling part of developing Phoenix apps. I submitted an [issue against phoenix](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2254) a couple days ago. No one has commented on it.

Comment: I came from java background, and really really not familiar with npm... in spring framework, adding js lib is just as simply as dump it in a folder and accessing it directly from jsp... I don't wanna get bother with npm problem with Win OS. If I can access additional js directly from template page would be good enough... so I can move on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using brunch.js by default, and your jquery file is being concatenated into app.js (you can change the order of the concatenation of files, check your `brunch-config.js`)
From now you would be able to access jquery global variable in your `/web/static/js/app.js` etc, also make sure if you need an inline script in your template, to place it after `<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "js/app.js") %> </script>`